# MySQL Joins returns NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join two tables names Students and Subjects, I need to use both tables for one search query, this is my search query:

```
SELECT
  subjects.subject_name, students.first_name, 
  students.last_name, subjects.examboard, students.student_id
FROM subjects
  RIGHT JOIN students
  ON Subjects.subject_id=students.student_id
WHERE examboard='OCR'
ORDER BY last_name ASC
```

My results:
The ExamBoard (OCR) that shows up... The rest?? Null for every single one of them.

With Inner join or Right join, it results in empty set.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Why would you join on Subjects.subject_id=students.student_id?  There is pretty much no way they should match.

Comment: `math = john doe`, basically?

Comment: Share information about the table please.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
middle_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
password CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
reg_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
UNIQUE (email));

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subjects(
Subject_ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Subject_Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
LevelOfEntry VARCHAR(30),
ExamBoard VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

Comment: You should be able to update your original question, rather than post such additions in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your mistake is where you're joining:

```
Subjects.subject_id=students.student_id
```

It probably should be:

```
Subjects.student_id=students.student_id
```

Also, where are these?

```
WHERE examboard='OCR'
ORDER BY last_name ASC
```

That is, what table are they in?  It's not specified, and it should be.

Comment: My friend is able to do this with success but if I try to than it fails.

Comment: I added the table names into the where and order by, still same result. I honestly do not understand this. My friend has the exact same table structure, but for him his results do not turn out as 'NULL'

Comment: Your trouble (looking at your tables), is that you do not HAVE a student_id to join on.  You need to add that.  Either that, or you need to add the subject_id to the student table (which is probably better.)  That way, each student has a reference to whatever subject they have.

Comment: Yes, I seem to not. Do you know any other command that would be relevant for me. The normal SELECT FROM WHERE returns the results, but it returns results not according to the values in both tables.

Comment: The whole point of a relational database is having record "relate" to each other.  You have no relationship.  You need to make one.

Comment: It's not a command that you're missing.  No command in the world will join your records when there is nothing to join.

Comment: My students table has all the students, my subjects table has all the subjects, I am trying to join them but I do not want to have one messy table, any suggestions?

Comment: Yes.  My suggestion is to add a subject_id column to your student table.  Populate that column with the subject_id that each student has.

Comment: @Rekan If students can be associated with multiple subjects and subjects can have multiple students, you are going to need a third table.

Comment: SELECT
  entries.examboard, subjects.subject_name, students.first_name, 
  students.last_name, students.student_id
FROM entries, subjects, students
  LEFT JOIN entries
  ON entries.student_id=students.student_id
WHERE entries.examboard='OCR'
ORDER BY last_name ASC

Comment: That is my new command, my entries table links to subjects and students to the entries table with a foreign key,

Comment: I get the error: ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'entries'

Comment: Okay...  Seriously...  You never mentioned the word "entries" before.  I think I will now abandon this thread.  If you need additional help, you may try again.

Comment: @Rekan you need to join students to entries to subjects, or vice versa; I generally stay away from comma notation, you don't need to reference that table twice, and you don't even a proper condition for entries and subjects...